# Pagination row numbering

Tags: php

So I can't get this to work.

I have the variable `$page` which contains the current page, `$total_pages` which contain the total amount of pages and `$limit` which contains the max number of rows per page.

I have tried doing a lot of stuff but I just don't get it.

This is the latest thing I tried. It works for page 1 & 2 but then it just stops working

```
if ($page == 1) {
        $count = 1;
    } else {
        $count = $page * $limit/2 + 1;
    }
```

That code was above my while-loop which loops out the rows.

Comment: Can you show more code context?

Comment: OK. So what's your question?

Comment: What is `$count` supposed to be?

Comment: actually I think it would be easier in the query

Comment: Is this being used in a SQL `LIMIT offset, rowcount` clause?

Comment: Why `$limit/2`?  If you are trying to get the record number for the first record on X page, that would be calculated as this: `$first_row_num = (($page_num - 1) * $page_limit) + 1;`  This will work for all page numbers.  You shouldn't need different logic for different page numbers. Note I am assuming that `$page_num` is a value >= 1 (not 0 based).

Comment: And if it's being used for the offset in LIMIT, get rid of `+ 1`, since it counts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is :

```
if ($page == 1) {
    $count = 1;
} else {
    $count = ($page - 1) * $limit + 1;
}
```

It is equal to what you tried for $page = 1 or 2, that's why it worked. This is even shorter and works whaterver the value of `$page` :

```
$count = ($page - 1) * $limit + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think through the simple math here.

If `$page` is a value >= 1, than the first row on each page would be calculated as follows:

```
$first_row_num = (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1;
```

You should not need different logic branch for first page vs. other pages.

Also note that when dealing with page numbers, that you will need to use zero-based page numbers when querying the database.  So you need to do something like this before querying the database.

```
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
```

And in your LIMIT clause you would use:

```
... LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

So considering you need to calculate the offset before displaying results, you might actually do something like:

```
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
// make DB query here
// now calculate first row number using $offset
$first_row_num = $offset + 1;
```